# Bug in Weaviate - Update data object instance (Python Client)

Tags: python, database, vector, weaviate

I have a Weaviate instance running (ver 1.12.2)

I am playing around with the Python client https://weaviate-python-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ (ver 3.4.2) (add - retrieve - delete objects...etc...)

I have come across a weird bug when trying to update  a data object.

I am following the example under the *update()* function at https://weaviate-python-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/weaviate.data.html

I first add a data object

```
author_id = client.data_object.create(
    data_object = {'name': 'Philip Pullman', 'age': 64},
    class_name = 'Author'
)
```

I then retrieve it with `client.data_object.get(author_id)`. This gives me a good output

```
{'class': 'Author',
 'creationTimeUnix': 1650911164482,
 'id': '00643310-bdd4-47b3-b404-d0aa7c9331f5',
 'lastUpdateTimeUnix': 1650911164482,
 'properties': {'age': 64, 'name': 'Philip Pullman'},
 'vectorWeights': None}
```

This works fine, but when I try to **update** the object with :

```
client.data_object.update(
    data_object = {'age': 74},
    class_name = 'Author',
    uuid = author_id
)
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnexpectedStatusCodeException             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-84003038f15b> in <module>
----> 1 client.data_object.update(
      2     data_object = {'age': 74},
      3     class_name = 'Author',
      4     uuid = author_id
      5 )

~/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpu_dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/weaviate/data/crud_data.py in update(self, data_object, class_name, uuid, vector)
    246             # Successful merge
    247             return
--> 248         raise UnexpectedStatusCodeException("Update of the object not successful", response)
    249 
    250     def replace(self,

UnexpectedStatusCodeException: Update of the object not successful! Unexpected status code: 500, with response body: {'error': [{'message': 'repo: merge into index author: shard Iomjx2uCohtc: update vector index: insert doc id 1 to vector index: insert called with nil-vector'}]}
```

***Moreover*** the annoying thing is that the update has been made in the background !

Running: `client.data_object.get(author_id)` again, gives the output:

```
{'class': 'Author',
 'creationTimeUnix': 1650911164482,
 'id': '00643310-bdd4-47b3-b404-d0aa7c9331f5',
 'lastUpdateTimeUnix': 1650911164482,
 'properties': {'age': 74, 'name': 'Philip Pullman'},
 'vectorWeights': None}
```

***The 'age' field has been updated appropriately***

**Also.... shouldn't `lastUpdateTimeUnix` also be updated?**

Thanks for reading my Q !

Comment: Going by ... https://github.com/semi-technologies/weaviate-python-client/blob/main/weaviate/data/crud_data.py.  It looks like it doesn't like the response code it is getting. Its looking for a 204 status response...which it is not getting.

I'm not familiar with these responses 200/204/404 so that's as far as I go

Comment: Thanks. The current assumption is that this is a bug when a vector index is configured, but an object has no vector attached. This combination was impossible up until recently. It seems that while creating and replacing works, patching creates an issue. We are tracking the bug here: https://github.com/semi-technologies/weaviate/issues/1936

Comment: good stuff. I think this has been addressed.

Comment: Turned out to be a bug - it was addressed : https://github.com/semi-technologies/weaviate/issues/1936

Comment: Correct, as soon as that fix goes live I will add an answer with some details and links to the version including the fix.